# How to zip only specific type of files in a directory with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    files = [os.listdir]
    files_to_zip = []
    for file in files:
        if str(file).__contains__("png"):
            files_to_zip.append(file)
    shutil.make_archive("test", 'zip', files_to_zip)
```

My code is as above. I know it shouldn't work but I really want to understand the logic behind. I want to make a zip archive of the all *.png files in the current directory and then remove them all. Right now I can make a zip file containing all the files in the directory but I only want the png files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). `files_to_zip = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.png"))`

Comment: `glob.glob('*.png')`

Comment: files_to_zip = glob.glob(str(os.getcwd(), "*.png") I tried this and got this error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: `[os.listdir]`? Really?

Comment: @Taha, compare your code with provided in comments...

Comment: @MadPhysicist Bro I am just starting to learn :D Don't kill my will for it please

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes I tried yours as it is but it throws cant be list error.

Comment: A valuable tool is debugger or print statements. With either of those, you could see that `files` is a list containing a function object. You need to actually call the function: `files = os.listdir()`. It returns a list, so no need to wrap it in another one.

Comment: Let me be more precise about my question. I want to zip the png files in the current working directory. Right now my problem is I cant pass os.getcwd() as a parameter to glob.glob()

Answer (score 1):

I think the pathlib module is easier to use.

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = <YOUR DIRECTORY>
shutil.make_archive("test", 'zip', Path(directory).glob('*.png'))
```

Comment: pathlib is incidental here. You could just as easily have used the glob module

Comment: But pathlib produces an iterable of Path() objects which have the ability to access any other method in the pathlib module. In general, everyone should be switching over to the pathlib module, it was specifically designed to incorporate all the path like functions in one place. It also works seamlessly on windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os import shutil from unittest.mock import patch

_os_path_isfile = os.path.isfile


def accept(path):
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path)
    if file_extension not in [".py", ".ipynb"]:
        return False
    print("archiving %r" % path)
    return _os_path_isfile(path)



with patch("os.path.isfile", side_effect=accept):
    shutil.make_archive("archive_file_name", "zip", ".")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).